# Getting "The method is undefined for the type String"

Tags: java, syntax

I am a newbie following the book 'Head First Java', and following one of the projects in the book. I ran into an error on the last line of the main method - "The method checkYourself(String) is undefined for the type String"

```
class dotcom{
    int [] Locationcells;
    int hits = 0;

public String checkYourself(String guess){
    int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);
    String result = "miss";

    for(int cell : Locationcells){
        if(guess1 == cell){
            result = "hit";
            hits = hits + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hits == Locationcells.length){
        result = "kill";



    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;


}
public void setCellLocations(int []locs){
    Locationcells = locs;

}
}




public class SimpleDotComGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dotcom dotMan = new dotcom();
        int locations [] = {3,4,5};
        dotMan.setCellLocations(locations);


        String userguess = "2";
        String result = userguess.checkYourself(userguess);



}
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: Look at what you're calling the `checkYourself` method on. Now look at the class it's declared in.

Comment: There's no `String#checkYourself` method.

Comment: String is a class that is not defined by you - it does not have 'checkYourself' method - that is all. It is a method defined in your 'dotcom' class.

Comment: @Paecko this goes to show that you need to `checkYourself` before you `wreckYourself`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a method `checkYourself` for the String value

```
userguess.checkYourself(userguess);
```

... which doesn't exists for the String class.

It should be

```
dotMan.checkYourself(userguess);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to do

```
String result = dotman.checkYourself(userguess);
```

instead of

```
String result = userguess.checkYourself(userguess);
```

The error message means that `checkYourself` is not a method in the `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

result = dotMan.checkYourself(userguess)